# UWP NavigationView switch to another page via MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, navigationview, navigationservice

Switching for the first time ever from WPF to UWP I found out that there are great controls like `SplitView` and `NavgiationView` do exist in the world of UWP.

For renewing my current home-project I have choosen the `NavigationView` control as my main UI control for offering the various pieces of information.
Using the code-behind the page navigation ([as shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_06UZhaJMc)) is very easy, but for my use-case I want to work with MVVM (as a learning procedure without using FWs like MVVMLIght or similar).

Currently, my `NavigationView` looks like this; but I have not a proper idea how to change within the frame through pages (from my understanding I have to use the `NavigationService` but haven't found a easy to understand example of this):

```
<NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" IsPaneOpen="False"  IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False" CompactModeThresholdWidth="0" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" Background="Black" Foreground="Black"
        Loaded="nvTopLevelNav_Loaded"
        Margin="0,12,0,0"
        SelectionChanged="nvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged"
        ItemInvoked="nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked"
        IsTabStop="False"
                IsSettingsVisible="False"
                AlwaysShowHeader="False"
        Header="asdasdaasdasdasd">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="Home_Page" />
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Globe" Content="Weather" Tag="Weather_Page" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="My Agenda" Tag="Agenda_Page">
    <!-- some custom PathIcon -->
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact" Content="My News" Tag="News_Page" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"></Frame>
</NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP NavigationView switch to another page via MVVM

For your requirement, you could use [`Windows Template Studio`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio) to create UWP project that contain MVVM pattern and `NavigationService`.

```
private void OnItemInvoked(NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsViewModel).FullName);
        return;
    }

    var item = _navigationView.MenuItems
                    .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
                    .First(menuItem => (string)menuItem.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
    var pageKey = item.GetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty) as string;
    NavigationService.Navigate(pageKey);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit this is the solution, but the code is not really self-explanatory. It uses "ActionServices", which agian are completely new for me. But thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of my blog about solution i came up with without any 3rd party api, there is  also github repot with the solution.

https://kwodarczyk.github.io/UwpWinUI3PageMVVMNavigation/

All you need it attached property that allows to pass view model type to your datatempalte

```
public class ViewModelContext : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "ViewModelContext",
      typeof(Type),
      typeof(ViewModelContext),
      new PropertyMetadata(null)
    );
    public static void SetType(DependencyObject element, Type value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TypeProperty, value);
    }
    public static Type GetType(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (Type)element.GetValue(TypeProperty);
    }
}
```

example datatempalte:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PageOne" viewModels:ViewModelContext.Type="viewModels:PageOneViewModel">
   <views:PageOne/>
</DataTemplate>
```

and  custom template selector where you can match the template agatis the view model

```
public class CustomTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var viewModeltype = item.GetType();

            foreach (var rd in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
            {
                foreach (var value in rd.Values)
                {
                    if (value is DataTemplate dataTempate)
                    {
                        Type contexType = dataTempate.GetValue(ViewModelContext.TypeProperty) as Type;

                        if (contexType != null && contexType == viewModeltype)
                        {
                            return dataTempate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```